# returning status once the file is written to local from s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

trying to fetch a file from s3 bucket and storing it on the local, once its written to the local reading the file from the local and converting the data to json format and sending it.

i need to check whether the file is downloaded and written to local, once the file exist only read and convert it to json else send an error message.

once the file is on open i am writing the file and making end. So after end i can't send a return value. So how i can solve this one and use try catch to send proper error message.

```
const fetchFileDownloadAndWriteIt = () => {
 let Bucket = "DataBucket";
 let filename = "sample_data.csv";
 let s3 = new AWS.S3();
 const params = {
   Bucket: Bucket,
   Key: filename
 };

 return s3.getObject(params)
          .promise()
          .then(data => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream('./localdata/' + filename);
            file.on("open", () => {
             file.write(data.Body);
             file.end();  
            })
            .on("error", err => {
               console.log("Error Occured while writing", err.message)
             })
          })
            .catch(err => {
             console.log("unable to fetch file from s3 Bucket", err.message)
          })


}


exports.fetchData = async (req,res) => {
  let fileDownloadAndWrite = await fetchFileAndDownloadWriteIt();
  // need to check file is downloaded and written properly
  const path = "./localdata/sample_data.csv";
  const json = await csv().fromFile(path);
  res.send({data: json})

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `new Promise` instead of the one instead of the one you get by calling the `SDK's` API.

```
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    s3.getObject(params)
        .promise()
        .then(data => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream('./localdata/' + filename);
            file
                .on("open", () => {
                    file.write(data.Body);
                    file.end();
                    //success
                    res();
                })
                .on("error", err => {
                    rej(err);
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            rej(err);
        })
});
```

This will resolve to `undefined` and rejected with the proper error occured, like while writing file, etc.

**How to Call it in your handler?**

Something like this would be fine.

```
exports.fetchData = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await fetchFileDownloadAndWriteIt();
        // need to check file is downloaded and written properly - here the file is actually downloaded and written properly.
        const path = "./localdata/sample_data.csv";
        const json = await csv().fromFile(path);
        res.send({ data: json })
    }
    catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: so on exports.fetchData i should use try catch isn't

Comment: exports.fetchData = async (req,res) => {
  try{
   let fileDownloadAndWrite = await fetchFileAndDownloadWriteIt();
   if(fileDownloadAndWrite === undefined){
   const path = "./localdata/sample_data.csv";
   const json = await csv().fromFile(path);
   res.send({data: json})
   }
  }
  catch(err){
   res.send({error: err.message})
  }
}

Comment: yes, In fact you should always use `try...catch` for an `async` request handler otherwise you can get an unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: can you just add the if condition too on the try block . So it will be helpful for others

Comment: i have edited it can  you just review it and update your answer

Comment: I think there is no use of `if` statement here as the `fetch...()` would always resolve to undefined or would throw error that would be catched by the `catch` block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184296/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-vibhor1997a).

Comment: but how can i confirm that the file is downloaded , once the file is downloaded and written only the try block should execute. await will be executed parallel isn't

Comment: also how can send the error message, in your answer its just return next(err), it should be res.send({error: err.message])

Comment: as you have made your function `async` the function would itself be asynchronous and return a `promise` but internal statements would execute in a synchronized fashion. first your `await fetchFileDownloadAndWriteIt()` would happen then `        const path = "./localdata/sample_data.csv";` and so on.

Comment: That is up to you how you handle the errors and what kind of message and logging you want to do. I was just illustrating.

Comment: so res.send({error: err.message}) inside catch block will catch all the two errors on file writing error and any error occur on s3 isn't

Comment: yes it would catch errors while downloading from s3 and also while writing file.

Comment: once the fetchFileDownloadAndWriteIt() function execute only (i mean completely execute gives success or error) then only the ` const path = "./localdata/sample_data.csv";`  const json = await csv().fromFile(path);
         res.send({ data: json }) will execute

Comment: yes, that is the case. If the call to your `fetch..` function is successful then only the statements below it would execute.